# awk -Search pattern through Variable

Tags: awk

We have wrote shell script for multiple file name search pattern.

**file format:**

```
<number>_<20180809>.txt
```

starting with **single number** and ending with **8 digits** number

**Command:**

```
awk -v string="12_1234" -v serch="^[0-9]+_+[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$" "BEGIN{ if (string ~/serch$/) print string }"
```

If sting matches then return value.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change your command in the following way and it will work:

```
awk -v string='12_1234' -v search='^[0-9]+_+[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$' 'BEGIN{ if (string ~ search) print string }'                
12_1234
```

You do not need to use `/.../` syntax for regex if you use the `~` operator and also you had one extra `$`. You were really close!!!

Then you must adapt the search regex into `^[0-9]_[0-9]{8}$ to match exactly your`_<20180809>` pattern.

Also if you are just extracting this information from the file you can use `grep`,

```
$ awk -v string='1_12345678' -v search='^[0-9]_[0-9]{8}$' 'BEGIN{ if (string ~ search) print string }'                           
1_12345678

$ (search='^[0-9]_[0-9]{8}$'; echo '1_12345678')| grep -oE "$search"
1_12345678
```

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks Ed, you are completely right! ;-) Fixed!